# How to limit connection pool size in monk Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, monk

I am using monk module to get data from mongodb. But as soon as I connect to db it creates 5 connections.

This is my command line mongodb server console...

```
 2015-05-14T10:32:35.618+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from
    127.0.0.1:61015 #3 (2 connections now open)
2015-05-14T10:32:35.619+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from
 127.0.0.1:61016 #4 (3 connections now open)
2015-05-14T10:32:35.621+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from
 127.0.0.1:61017 #5 (4 connections now open)
2015-05-14T10:32:35.621+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from
 127.0.0.1:61018 #6 (5 connections now open)
2015-05-14T10:32:35.622+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from
 127.0.0.1:61019 #7 (6 connections now open)
2015-05-14T10:32:35.629+0530 I NETWORK  [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:61015 (
5 connections now open)
2015-05-14T10:32:35.629+0530 I NETWORK  [conn4] end connection 127.0.0.1:61016 (
5 connections now open)
2015-05-14T10:32:35.629+0530 I NETWORK  [conn5] end connection 127.0.0.1:61017 (
5 connections now open)
2015-05-14T10:32:35.629+0530 I NETWORK  [conn6] end connection 127.0.0.1:61018 (
5 connections now open)
2015-05-14T10:32:35.629+0530 I NETWORK  [conn7] end connection 127.0.0.1:61019 (
5 connections now open)
```

Comment: any success with this issue?

Comment: Instead of monk use mongoose.

Comment: It has good support.

Answer (score 0):

Set `monk` connection pool size as follows:

```
const monk = require('monk');
const db = monk('localhost/mydb', {
  poolSize: 7 // number of connections
});
```

It defaults to `5`.

Source: https://automattic.github.io/monk/docs/manager/